# Rails 5.2 cache key for relations generating two queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, activesupport

I have a view using fragment caching for an `ActiveRecord` relation, e.g.

```
<% cache MyModel.all do %>
...
<% end %>
```

I see two DB queries generated in this case

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("my_model"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "my_model"`
2. `SELECT "my_model".* from "my_model"`

I expect the first one, and it's usually a much more efficient query. I did not expect the second one.

If I instead use:

```
<% cache ActiveSupport::Cache.expand_cache_key(MyModel.all) do %>
...
<% end %>
```

then I get only the first query with the same resulting cache key.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: narrowed down to where this happens: see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29092#issuecomment-437572543

> when
>   [`normalize_version`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/09ca939eabc8b0cda865ecf2893c48800a7c51e3/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L668-L678)
>   is executed, the relation does not respond to `cache_version`, and
>   therefore ends up being expanded with
>   [`to_a`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/09ca939eabc8b0cda865ecf2893c48800a7c51e3/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L676).
>   So essentially, calling `Product.all.to_a` and then for each object
>   calling `cache_version`, which returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this does look like a bug. Hopefully this would be [fixed on this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34378), since my own PR for a stopgap fix was [rejected](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34503#issuecomment-440809778)